# how to change redirect default login link based on role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I have two controllers the first have authorized filter based on user role and the second on admin role like this `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` if an unauthorized end user tries to access any action in the controller with admin authorization I want to redirect to an error page else redirect to user login page.

this code in the startup class

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            CookieName = "AseelCokie"
    });
```

I want something like this

```
 string path;
        if (Role == "Admin") //here i want to check Role of controller
            path = "/Home/ErrorPage";
        else
            path = "/Account/Login";
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
            LoginPath = new PathString(path),
            CookieName = "AseelCokie"
    });
```